# ssh from mac to linux access denied

Tags: macos, ssh, access-denied, openssh

**information**

I'm running an Ubuntu Server 13.10. I can connect to it using SSH from any computer except my laptop (MacBook 2007, OSX 10.6.8). When I try to connect to the server, it will always be added to the host.deny. 
Nevertheless it is possible to connect to the server of my university with denyhost active.
When I'm connected to the university server, it is also possible to connect to mine using the same command.

/var/log/denyhosts:

```
2014-08-31 22:49:28,183 - denyhosts   : INFO     new denied hosts: ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx']
2014-08-31 22:49:28,183 - denyhosts   : INFO     new suspicious logins: ['username - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx']
2014-08-31 22:49:58,283 - denyhosts   : INFO     new suspicious logins: ['username - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx']
```

**question**

What would cause such strange behaviour, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

I posted the question on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/625453/when-ssh-from-mac-to-ubuntu-server-it-will-be-added-to-hosts-deny)

Comment: http://serverfault.com is probably a better place to ask this.

Comment: @MikeS - please familiarize yourself with the charter of SF before referring posters there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DeerHunter Apologies, I got that wrong. I looked at server fault and super user and I felt that server fault was a better fit, but I see now that it mentions that it's not for anything in a home or development environment, which is a category this probably falls in to. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server, here are your options.

Almost always for it to work, you need to use a VNC service so that you have a university ip address. I'm sure your university has one, just google it. Is it possible that your ip is different between computers?

My research group at the university has an NFS server. To mount it with mounting scripts, you need a university static ip address (ethernet required) and you need to be added by a server admin. Is it connected wifi or ethernet, and is possible that the other computers you have are on the admin list?

A program called Transmit ($35) will allow you to mount a server with just ssh credentials. Transmit also has the ability to act like rsync. There is a trial, so you can check to see if you can access it with Transmit.

It's also worth a try to to use rsync.